# Spring-Data-Rest supports KeySet Pagination?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

The current Spring-Data-Rest pagination will be very slow once the data in the table grow huge (200Million+ rows).
Does anyone know if there is a capability for Spring-Data-Rest to use KeySet Pagination instead of the current one?

Has anyone tried to implement this?

Please and Thank you in advance!